# Codec not found for requested operation: [TEXT <-> java.time.LocalDate]

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, codec, localdate

This is the code which I am using to fill the column in the db.

```
DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
JSONObject publishedObj = jsonObject.optJSONObject("created");
                    if(publishedObj != null){
                        String dateStr = publishedObj.getString("value");
                        book.setPublishedDate(LocalDate.parse(dateStr,dateFormat));
                    }
```

Below is the instance variable of the column where the data needs to go:

```
@Column("published_date")
@CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.DATE)
private LocalDate publishedDate;
```

Error Message which i am getting:

```
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.codec.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [TEXT <-> java.time.LocalDate]
```

Can please someone help.
Thankyou!!

Comment: check types between database & your code. It looks like you have field as `text` in the database

Comment: Exactly what @AlexOtt said.  Can you post your table definition?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce that error with your code above.  To remedy it, I have `ALTER`ed the `book_by_id` table with two new columns:

```
ALTER TABLE book_by_id ADD pubdate2 TEXT;
ALTER TABLE book_by_id ADD pubdate3 DATE;
```

My `BookEntity` class for those columns looks like this:

```
@Column("pubdate2")
@CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.TEXT)
private String publishedDate2;

@Column("pubdate3")
@CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.DATE)
private LocalDate publishedDate3;
```

The code to parse and set the date looks like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
String dateStr = "2022-03-03T09:52:33.235555";
musicBook.setPublishedDate2(LocalDate.parse(dateStr,dateFormat).toString()); 
musicBook.setPublishedDate3(LocalDate.parse(dateStr,dateFormat));
        
template.insert(musicBook);
```

**tl;dr;**

Redefine `published_date` as a `DATE` type, and it will work. Besides, dates/times should be stored in date/time types in databases.

Note that Cassandra won't allow you to modify a column's data type.  Also, the process of dropping and adding a column with the same name in quick succession has proven to be problematic with Cassandra in the past.  I'd advise adding a newly named column of a `DATE` type, and reloading its data.  Or recreate the table (with the correct data  types) and reload the data.